# Why the treatment of connect() and connect(timeout) is different in Jsch Channel?

Tags: java, jsch

I'm considering setting explicitly the timeout for my Jsch connections (default is 20s) but I found out that the behavior is different if a timeout is passed as argument or not.

```
public void connect() throws JSchException{
    connect(0);
}

public void connect(int connectTimeout) throws JSchException{
    this.connectTimeout=connectTimeout;
    try{
        sendChannelOpen();
        start();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        connected=false;
        disconnect();
        if(e instanceof JSchException)
            throw (JSchException)e;
        throw new JSchException(e.toString(), e);
    }
}
```

In the first case you have a single wait of the timeout duration and in the second case you have 2000 retries of 10ms.

```
    protected void sendChannelOpen() throws Exception {
        Session _session=getSession();
        if(!_session.isConnected()){
            throw new JSchException("session is down");
        }

        Packet packet = genChannelOpenPacket();
        _session.write(packet);

        int retry=2000;
        long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
        long timeout=connectTimeout;
        if(timeout!=0L) retry = 1;
        synchronized(this){
            while(this.getRecipient()==-1 &&
                    _session.isConnected() &&
                    retry>0){
                if(timeout>0L){
                    if((System.currentTimeMillis()-start)>timeout){
                        retry=0;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                try{
                    long t = timeout==0L ? 10L : timeout;
                    this.notifyme=1;
                    wait(t);
                }
                catch(java.lang.InterruptedException e){
                }
                finally{
                    this.notifyme=0;
                }
                retry--;
            }
        }
        if(!_session.isConnected()){
            throw new JSchException("session is down");
        }
        if(this.getRecipient()==-1){  // timeout
            throw new JSchException("channel is not opened.");
        }
        if(this.open_confirmation==false){  // SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE
            throw new JSchException("channel is not opened.");
        }
        connected=true;
    }
```

Does anybody knows what is the explanation of that ?

Thanks

Comment: You're right about the behavior. If you don't pass the timeout arg it will retry `2000` times, `10`ms each. If you pass the timeout arg it will set retry count to `1` and wait for the custom timeout ms. TBH the JSch library code is a mess.

Comment: To be fair with Jsch, I use it intensively for several years and the library is extremely robust and flexible. Maybe not the most commented code ever, but it's a very reliable brick to build on.